# Loading Animation between 2 components

Tags: angular, angular-material, frontend, loading

How can i put a loading screen while waitging for the other component to load,

For example, on my register page, it takes 8seconds to load to the other component, how can I put loading animation between those two, I'm using router outlet on traversing btw.

Comment: I'm using Laravel for the backend.

Comment: I hope this proves useful to you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mwQFRsuY5i8